# Is it possible for my android app to read folders other than its private data folder in internal storage?

Tags: android, permissions, storage, internal

As an app developer, I want to enable users to browse internal storage and SD card, and then to select a picture file to show after a 'select image' button is tapped.

For example, users can select a pic from \Pictures folder, \Downloads folder, or any other folders in internal storage, as well as folders in SD card. It's some like a mobile users is browsing internal storage & SD card via a stock 'Files Explorer' app.

I have declared READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in my app manifest file. So, my app works well for pic files in SD card folders.

My question is, is it possible for my app to read folders, such as \Pictures, \Downloads,...and so on, which are other than its private data folder, in internal storage? If yes, what permission should I declare in manifest? Or what should I do for this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes of course your app can read all those folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in manifest file, App can access all directories of internal storage.
No other permissions are require.